# What is an example of a c++ forwarditerator?

Tags: c++, iterator, generic-programming

I am looking for an example of an iterator which satisfies the limited qualities to be considered a ForwardIterator, while not being anything else in the hierarchy of iterators.

I have written a program which prints which of the five iterator categories an iterator conforms to. I have tested it for the other four iterator categories.

Comment: A forward iterator would be an iterator of a singly linked list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical example is `std::forward_list<T>::iterator`. Testing snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <forward_list>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
bool test = std::is_same <
                typename std::iterator_traits <
                    typename T::iterator
                >::iterator_category,
                std::forward_iterator_tag
            >::value ;

int main()
{
    // test wheter std::forward_list's iterator is a forward_iterator
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << test<std::forward_list<int>> << std::endl;
    // what about std::vector?
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << test<std::vector<int>>;
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4af357422c00938)</kbd>